# How to set cell margins of tables in ms word using python docx

Tags: python, python-docx

As far as I understand you can only change cell width of table.

Answer (score 6):

I use this snippet to modify margins of a cell

```
def set_cell_margins(cell: _Cell, **kwargs):
    """
    cell:  actual cell instance you want to modify

    usage:

        set_cell_margins(cell, top=50, start=50, bottom=50, end=50)

    provided values are in twentieths of a point (1/1440 of an inch).
    read more here: http://officeopenxml.com/WPtableCellMargins.php
    """
    tc = cell._tc
    tcPr = tc.get_or_add_tcPr()
    tcMar = OxmlElement('w:tcMar')

    for m in [
        "top",
        "start",
        "bottom",
        "end",
    ]:
        if m in kwargs:
            node = OxmlElement("w:{}".format(m))
            node.set(qn('w:w'), str(kwargs.get(m)))
            node.set(qn('w:type'), 'dxa')
            tcMar.append(node)

    tcPr.append(tcMar)
```

you can read more about openxml tags here http://officeopenxml.com/WPtableCellMargins.php

Comment: What is the `cell` argument? Cell instance?

Comment: yeah, cell instance, for example table.rows[1].cells[0]

Comment: But the function don't return anything, how can i use the modified cell instance?

Comment: This function don't create any new cells, it just affects cell instance you passed to function, so you can can continue work with cell instance you passed  set_cell_margins(cell, top=50, start=50, bottom=50, end=50); cell.value = "test"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but the code suggested by MadisonTrash doesn't work for me. That's with Word 365.
I have an alternative that does the trick for me:

```
def set_cell_margins(table, left=0, right=0):

    tc = table._element
    tblPr = tc.tblPr
    tblCellMar = OxmlElement('w:tblCellMar')
    kwargs = {"left":left, "right":right}
    for m in ["left","right"]:
        node = OxmlElement("w:{}".format(m))
        node.set(qn('w:w'), str(kwargs.get(m)))
        node.set(qn('w:type'), 'dxa')
        tblCellMar.append(node)

    tblPr.append(tblCellMar)
```

Note that this is working on the level of the Table, not the Cell.